# Array javascript output

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

How to recover the elements of a foreach for reformed in this way:

```
['julie','nicola','sahra']
```

My code

```
   var outPutStats = ''
    client.data.forEach(function(element) {
         outPutStats += [element.name];
    }); 
    .............................
    .............................

        xAxis: {
            name: [outPutStats] // Must be ['dataName1','dataName2']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
```

Comment: what's client.data look like?

Comment: do you want `outPutStats` to be an array or a string?

Comment: @Paul is a array, one by one name is `client.torrents[0].name`

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir In string I supose, it must come out in this way: `['julie','nicola','sahra']`

Comment: @atmon3r I don't follow. You want the `outPutStats` to be like this: `['julie','nicola','sahra']` or like this `"['julie','nicola','sahra']"`?

Comment: Please show `client.data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var outputStats = [];
client.data.forEach(function(element) { 
  outputStats.push(element.name);
});
```

It's probably more semantically accurate to use `Array#map` instead, though, if the clients you want support it (which afaik they should if they support forEach):

```
var outputStats = client.data.map(function(element) { return element.name; });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy `client.data` into a new array `outPutStats` then this will work (although I don't see the reason why, you could just use `client.data`):

```
// This must be an array
var outPutStats = [];
client.data.forEach(function(element) {
    // fill the array with elements
    outPutStats.push(element.name);
}); 
// ...
// ...

xAxis: {
    name: outPutStats // outPutStats is already an array
},
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },
```

Comment: He's trying to transform the array content, is why he is not just using `client.data`.

Comment: @torazaburo Why poor? It does the same thing. Plus I just keeped the same format as the question. (he used `forEach` so I used it as well to keep things clear).

Comment: This use case is the entire raison d'etre of `map`. And yes, you are allowed, indeed encouraged, to suggest ways to improve the OP's code, rather than slavishly copy sub-optimal parts of it.